# Images are not displaying in slide show using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code and tried many other codes to display images in slide. but all in vain.. no error is in my code but not a single image is displaying on web page.. my code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body{

    background-color: black;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:320px;
    height:480px;

}
img{
    -webkit-transition-property:opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration:3s;
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
    height:auto;

}
img.fade-out{opacity:0;}
img.fade-in{opacity:1;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src = "Slide1.JPEG";/>
<img src = "Slide2.JPEG";/>
<img src = "Slide3.JPEG";/>
<img src = "Slide4.JPEG";/>


var interval = 4 * 20;

var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imageArray = [];
var imageCount = images.length;
var current =0;

var randomize = funtion() {

    return ( Math.round(Math.random() * 3 - 1.5 ));
}

for(var i=0; i<imageCount; i++) {

    images[i].className = 'fade-out';

    imageArray[i] = images[i];
}

imageArray.sort(randomize);

var fade = function() {

    imageArray[current++].className = 'fade-out';

    if(current == imageCount) {

        current = 0;

        imageArray.sort(randomize);

    }

imageArray[current].className = 'fade-in';

setTimeout(fade,interval * 100);

};
fade();
</script>
}

</body>
</html>
```

Please guide me where is the error.
Thanks

Comment: you are missing `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error:

```
Yor aur using file type in caps (.JPEG) it should be .jpeg / .jpg
```

Second error:

```
You forget to type the <script> tag at the starting of JavaScript code.
```

Third error:

```
You are using invalid function keyword (funtion) 

var randomize = "funtion"() {
    return ( Math.round(Math.random() * 3 - 1.5 ));
}
```

Now put this code and it should work...

```
    <html>
<head>

<style>
```

body{

```
background-color: black;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:320px;
height:480px;
```

}

```
img{
-webkit-transition-property:opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration:3s;
position:absolute;
width:320px;
height:auto;
```

}

```
img.fade-out{opacity:0;}
img.fade-in{opacity:1;}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<img src = "Slide1.jpg" />
<img src = "Slide2.jpg" />
<img src = "Slide3.jpg" />
<img src = "Slide4.jpg" />


<script>
var interval = 4 * 20;

var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

var imageArray = [];

var imageCount = images.length;

var current =0;

var randomize = function(){
return ( Math.round(Math.random() * 3 - 1.5 ));
}

for(var i=0; i<imageCount; i++) {
images[i].className = 'fade-out';
imageArray[i] = images[i];
```

}

```
imageArray.sort(randomize);

var fade = function() {
imageArray[current++].className = 'fade-out';
if(current == imageCount) {
    current = 0;
    imageArray.sort(randomize);
}

imageArray[current].className = 'fade-in';

setTimeout(fade,interval * 100);

};

fade();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. now images are displaying on web page... But there is another problem that slide show is not working.. on the top of the page these statements are displaying as it is and images are placed after one another...."body{ background-color: black; padding:0; margin:0; width:320px; height:480px; } img{ -webkit-transition-property:opacity; -webkit-transition-duration:3s; position:absolute; width:320px; height:auto; } img.fade-out{opacity:0;} img.fade-in{opacity:1;}"

Comment: could u please help me how do i select the images dynamically for the slide show... in this code images are fixed/hard coded. but if i want to select images from a particular folder than what i have to do? Thanks in advance

Comment: image should change automatically or need to change on page load only?

Comment: mean to say that in this code we know that how many images are to be displayed in the slide show and which ones... but i want to write a code in which any number of images stored in a folder could be displayed. total number of images should not a constant number. It may change.

Comment: dynamically select images and show them on slide show... number of images may vary from time to time...

Comment: Please visit it.. I have posted my question on this page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193611/dynamically-select-images-for-slide-show-using-javascript